# Html make full width for Video with custom Height

Tags: html, css

after read a lot of documents about this solution i can't resolve this problem, i want to show video with full width and custom height such as `width='100%' height='100px'`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="video-container">
        <video preload="auto" loop="" autoplay="" muted="" width="700px" height="50px">
            <source src="/uploads/MDclouds3-sunset.webmhd.webm"
                    type="video/webm">
            <source src="/uploads/MDclouds3-sunset-H.264-for-VP.m4v"
                    type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can i do that? thanks in advance

Comment: what about using inline styles? Like `<video style="width: 100%; height:100px;" . . . >`

Comment: @KidDoesCodingAndHasNoFriends not workin, video showing in small width, both of height and width are resized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 'object-fit' on the video.

Depending on what you need to do, `object-fit: fill` or `object-fit: contain` should do the trick:

https://codepen.io/manticorp/pen/jYXGRZ

note, if you want `object-fit:cover` you'll have to have a container whose dimensions are also `width: 100%; height: 100px;` and set `overflow:hidden;` on that.

Comment: Would recommend setting `height: auto;` as well

Comment: Object-fit for video doesn't work on MS Edge.  You can upvote to change this here https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/32011258-object-fit-and-object-position-for-all-media-eleme

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css section:

`video {
  width: 100%    !important;
  height: 100px  !important;
}`